# Description overflows into email address

Tags: bug, status-declined, profile-page

My email address is pretty long, and it gets eaten up by my description. Here's a screenshot of my [Apple Stack Exchange profile](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/19439/coffeerain)...

[image: Screenshot of profile]

The same thing happens on my Stack Overflow profile too. Could this get fixed somehow?

Comment: Well I can't repro this for *my* profiles on SE sites. What browser are you using?

Comment: Safari 5.0.2, but I set my default user agent to Firefox 3.6. (I know for sure Firefox 3.something)

Comment: And you do this because...? The awesomeness of WebKit is just too much for you to handle? Anyway, I *also* can't repro this in real Firefox 3.6 (which I just so happen to have installed).

Comment: A site for school prompts me to use Firefox 3.x, though Safari works with it. I access this site so often that I changed my default user agent so I could just use the site without warnings.

Comment: Hmm, you do have a very long email address, and email addresses are only visible to you and sometimes moderators, so this isn't a huge bug.  I'll ping [Jin](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/147574/jin), our designer, to see what he thinks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Jarrod said, your email is unusually long. We have limited space in that area. Your email address is only visible to you and the mods. In rare cases where the mods need to contact you, the email address is already a link, so it won't affect accessibility.